# Using svn+ssh with private key in JDeveloper 11.1.1.3

Tags: svn, ssh, ssh-keys, jdeveloper

I'm a consulting at a government agency. We have high security requirements all through the development process. Amongst other things, we are required to connect to our subversion repository over svn+ssh with private keys.
We are also bringing in some Oracle tech which requires us to develop in JDeveloper (11.1.1.3). Our worksations run Vista.

JDeveloper supports svn, by default through SVNKit, but also through JavaHL.
SVNKit supports svn+ssh with private keys. You can set the system property *svnkit.ssh2.key=path/to/private/key/file* to identify the key. I've tried setting this in my jdev.conf and I can see it's been set under Help/About/Properties, but I still get *svn: authentication failed. Please check your username and password.*

I've also tried getting JDeveloper to use JavaHL. Supposedly, you just install a binary distribution of svn, put the JavaHL DLL in the *bin* directory of the svn installation and make sure it is on the system path. I've tried this with the latest dists from both CollabNet and Slik, and an old svn-1.3.2 I found (JDev docs refer to this version). Supposedly, this should allow you to choose your svn implementation under Tools/Preferences/Versioning/Subversion, but only SVNKit shows up.

My questions:

1. Has anyone gotten svn+ssh with private key to work with SVNKit in JDeveloper?
2. Has anyone gotten JDeveloper to use JavaHL instead of SVNKit?
3. Has anyone gotten svn+ssh with private key to work with JavaHL in JDeveloper?

Obviously, if you answer 'yes' to any of the above, I'm interested in how? ;-)

Kind regards,

Lars Johansson

Comment: I should say, we successfully use JavaHL and PuTTY for Eclipse, so we know that part of the chain works...